# Javascript - How to capitalize first letter of each word

Tags: javascript, uppercase

```
 test <input type="text" id ="test" maxlength="20" onkeyup="myFunction()">
    <script>
        function myFunction(){
            var input = document.getElementById("test");
            var word = input.split(" ");
            for(var i = 0; i< word.length; i++){
                word[i] = word[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase()+word[i].slice(1).toLowerCase();
            }
            return word.join(" ");
        }            
    </script>
```

I tried in this way, but it does not work. What is the error in my code. Really appreciate it.

Comment: `document.getElementById("test").value` ???

Comment: Do you want it as you type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to get the value before spliting . As in `var word = input.value.split("")`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input = document.getElementById("test");
  var word = input.value.split(" ");
  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    word[i] = word[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word[i].slice(1).toLowerCase();
  }
  input.value = word.join(" ");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test" maxlength="20" onkeyup="myFunction()">
```

Comment: Or `onkeyup="this.value=myFunction()"`

Comment: @RayonDabre , yes it can be.

Comment: hi, it works. But i have a question about it. Why I could not use the return word.join(" "); and need to use input.value. Really appreciate it.

Comment: if you'd like to use @RayonDabre 's suggestion of `onkeyup="this.value=myFunction()"` , you need to use the `return word.join(" "); `

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of regExp

```
function camelize(str) {
  return str.replace(/(?:^\w|[A-Z]|\b\w)/g, function(letter, index) {
    return index == 0 ? letter.toLowerCase() : letter.toUpperCase();
  }).replace(/\s+/g, '');
}

camelize(input);
```

This is the best way to make Camel Case for strings using regExp.

Another way is using following function.

```
String.prototype.toUpperCaseFirstChar = function() {
    return this.substr( 0, 1 ).toUpperCase() + this.substr( 1 );
}
```

you can make call to this function like

```
input=input.toUpperCaseFirstChar
```

Answer (score 0):

You was not using .value with element object.

you need any string to split it.

https://jsfiddle.net/9hyw2vLb/3/

```
test <input type="text" id ="test" maxlength="20" onkeyup="return myFunction();">

        myFunction= function(){
            var input = document.getElementById("test").value;
            var word = input.split(" ");
            for(var i = 0; i< word.length; i++){
                word[i] = word[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase()+word[i].slice(1).toLowerCase();
            }
            console.log(word.join(" "));
            return word.join(" ");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using "java script" use CSS to style your form
`style="text-transform: capitalize;"` in the  tags
like
`<input type="text" id ="test" maxlength="20" style="text-transform: capitalize;">`

Comment: sorry, your right this doesn't change the value, if you do a `document.getElementById(id).value`, there will still be all lowercase

Answer (score 0):

Others have already answered correctly, but here's a version that uses method chaining. I find it more readable.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input = document.getElementById('test');

  var capitalizedWords =
    input
      .value
      .split(' ')
      .map(function(word) {
        return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase();
      })
      .join(' ');
  
  input.value = capitalizedWords;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test" maxlength="20" onkeyup="myFunction()">
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use CSS instead, this is much easier:

```
p.capitalize { text-transform: capitalize; }
```

Comment: sorry, what you mean by saying user typed case ?

Comment: This will not change the `case` of the characters but will display as it is changed...